# Sklearn linear regression predicting the incorrect value

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to use SKlearn to create a model to predict stock market prices. I know that stock market prediction is very difficult, but I think the results I am getting are quite wrong. Basically what I think is happening is that even if I set the labels to be the closing price for tomorrow, it predicts the closing price for today. Here is my code, and it is just supposed to be a skeleton, and I will go in and improve it more later.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn import linear_model
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, vplot
from bokeh.layouts import column
import shelve
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

d = shelve.open("shelve.slv")
def get_data(ticker):
    stock = d[ticker]
    return stock

def shuffle_two(arr1, arr2):
        list1_shuf = []
        list2_shuf = []
        index_shuf = list(range(len(arr1)))
        random.shuffle(index_shuf)
        for i in index_shuf:
            list1_shuf.append(arr1[i])
            list2_shuf.append(arr2[i])

        return list1_shuf, list2_shuf

def setup_data(stock, split, backtest = True):
    stock['HL_PCT'] = ((stock['High'] - stock["Low"]) / stock['Low']) * 100

    stock = stock[['Close', 'Volume', 'HL_PCT']]

    stock['Labels'] = stock['Close'].shift(-1)

    x = np.array(stock.drop(["Labels"], 1))
    stock.dropna(inplace = True)
    y = np.array(stock['Labels'])

    future_x = x[-1]
    x = x[:-1]

    train_x = list(x[:-split])
    train_y = list(y[:-split])
    test_x = list(x[-split:])
    test_y = list(y[-split:])

    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, future_x



stock = get_data('GOOGL')
train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, future_x = setup_data(stock, 1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
print (train_x[2])
print (train_y[2])
model.fit(train_x, train_y)
print (model.predict(future_x))
print (future_x)


#print (stock["Close"][-10:])
```

Whenever I try to output a prediction, I also print what I am predicting from. Here is that data:

```
[ 791.95367399]
[  7.92450012e+02   1.72830000e+06   1.73121034e+00]
```

The data is setup as closing price, volume and percentage difference between high and low prices. But if you look at it, the model is predicting 791.95, and the closing from today is 792.45, which are so close it is suspicious, especially judging by the fact that stock prices that are that high move by more than 50 cents each day. Do you see anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: "_Stock market prediction is very difficult_" - actually, it is impossible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis

Comment: @DYZ Then why do giant financial institutions like JPMorgan and others spend millions on machine learning specialists

Comment: Frankly, I am not so sure. But if someone could predict stock markets, someone would.

Comment: @DYZ if someone could predict the stock market accurately, why would they share it?

Comment: They would get rich disproportionately to all other players. But they don't. (Disclosure: I worked for TD AmeriTrade. They use data analysis to explain markets, not to predict them.)

Comment: @DYZ ok I understand that, but do you have any insight on my question?

Comment: The closing price of a stock on a particular day is probably tremendously correlated with the closing price of the same stock on the following day. Check the strengths correlations between each of your features and your labels. If the correlation is much stronger for closing price it is perfectly reasonable to get this result.

Comment: @morsecodist OK I understand that, but what should I do about it? I am a little confused

Comment: Well I am not sure what you are trying to do is achievable. A good place to start would be to analyze features in terms of correlation as I mentioned earlier. Based on these results you might want to add or remove certain features. Perhaps change what you are trying to predict i.e. relative shift from previous day's closing rather than just value.